# def with no args

Tags: scala, function

If I create a function:

```
def a(): String = return "some string"
```

the result would be "a: ()String"
So I can use it with/without brackets

On the other hand if I create the same function

```
def a:String = return "some other string"
```

It would be just "a: String"
and in this case I can't use it with brackets.

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Note: You can leave out the `return` keyword - in Scala, the result of a method is the value of the last expression in the method.

Comment: You can also avoid specifying def type. I just wanted to point out that it's a function, so that everyone will see that right away =)

Comment: But it isn't a function - it's a method. :) And I get this by the keyword `def`, don't I? Since most of the time, `return` is left out.

Comment: Again in book "Programming in Scala, 2nd edition" p72. "Function definitions start with def". Method is subroutine which belongs to some class or object. Yes, normally you don't put return statement, cause scala will take type from result of last statement. Anyway, this wasn't the main purpose of question.

Comment: @Konstantin Gorodinskiy: That is a well-known bug in the book. It's not a function, it's a method. That the book says "function" is just plain wrong.

Comment: thx, didn't know that such "bug" can exist almost on every page in a book of 2nd edition. That's bad. =(

Comment: @Konstantin It would be great if you could either accept an answer or tell us what other things you would like to know about this topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good practice recommends defining functions that have no side effect without `()`, and to add the `()` both at definition site and call site when the function has side effects (e.g., `println()` rather than `println`).

Answer (score 6):

If you define `a` like this, without parentheses (note, the `return` keyword is not necessary):

```
def a: String = "some other string"
```

and then call it with parenthesis: `a()`, then the `()` is not the empty argument list for the method `a`; instead, Scala will try to apply the `()` to the String that method `a` returns. The error message that you get when you try that hints to that:

```
scala> a()
<console>:7: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)Char in trait StringLike.
Unspecified value parameter n.
       a()
        ^
```

So, in the second case, `a()` means something else than in the first case. In the first case, it just means "call `a` with an empty argument list", and in the second case it means "call `a`, then apply `()` to the result of the method", which will fail on a `String`.

**edit** To expand on your second question in the comments below, it depends on what exactly you mean by "the same thing". As you saw in the REPL one looks like it has the type `()java.lang.String` while the other has the type `java.lang.String`. Have a look at the following, in which `x` and `y` turn into the same thing:

```
scala> def a() = "aaa"
a: ()java.lang.String

scala> def b = "bbb"
b: java.lang.String

scala> val x = a _
x: () => java.lang.String = <function0>

scala> val y = b _
y: () => java.lang.String = <function0>
```

Comment: You can also shrink this method to def a = "some string". I probably should rephrase my question. If I don't try to call the second function with brackets, both variants are the same thing?

Comment: In the book "Programming in Scala, 2nd edition" page 74, there is an example of def with no args. It says: "The empty parentheses indicate the function takes no parameters"(parenteses in result of scala interpreter). They are followed by def type. Scala interpreter also says that defs are equal. The thing that I don't understand is why the second notation doesn't understand brackety thing =) It's weird